# CouchDB update security object

Tags: couchdb

the command

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/somedb/_security -d '{"members":{"name":["foo"], "roles":[]}}'
```

insert the member named "foo" in the security object in "somedb" database.
But this command also delete the other members that are presents in the security object.
Is it possible update the members in the security object instead of overwrite them every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security objects does not keep previous revisions due to performance reasons. That means that there is no way to resolve conflicts and/or merge them.

Thus you have to GET the security object, modify it at client side and PUT it back.